# osmium processes piping stdin/stdout

Tags: osmium

I have tried to pipe several osmiums processes like this:

```
osmium tags-filter central-america-latest.osm.pbf r/admin_level=2 -f pbf | osmium tags-filter /dev/stdin -F pbf r/type=boundary -f pbf
```

But i get error:

> PBF error: blob does not have expected type (OSMHeader in first blob,
> OSMData in following blobs)

If i save output of first process in .pbf file, and read that file in second process there is no error and I get valid output result. Working on WSL2, Debian 9.
What did I do wrong with redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Osmium* potentially needs to read input files multiple times, or in parallel, which it can't after clearing STDIN; some commands thus don't have support for STDIN sources. The manual usually mentions availability for STDIN sources for individual tools explicitly.

---

<s>In your specific example you could simply chain filter expressions in the same command; make sure you write filter expressions in descending order of the estimated hit chance:</s>

```
osmium tags-filter central-america-latest.osm.pbf r/type=boundary,admin_level=2 -o <output_file.osm.pbf>
```

**Edit:**

No, apparently there's no `AND` command logic; intermediate files seems to be the only option.

Comment: Good observation for multiple & parallel reads! But chaining was first thing that I tried and it didn't work as expected. File size was bigger, and it looked like i was making an union of filters, not the intersection.

Ie. one of filters in chain is r/boundary=administrative, but i still get boundary=land_area in result.

Comment: And you know what? That's exactly what it does; my mistake, what you actually want is to chain by `,` (`AND`) - see updated expression

Comment: Tried that and result is unchanged, still like union.
From docs looks like `comma` is treated like `OR`, not `AND`.
https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-tags-filter.html

Comment: Well, you win: I updated with a disappointing conclusion...

Comment: I would rather let you win, but game is not over, maybe in some future version you will turn victorious and update this with some `AND` logic.